# jquery check checkboxes within an element only

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, checkbox

I have these audience groups with audiences hidden under it. When a user clicks on the audience group name, the hidden audiences will appear. now, what i want to do is when a user clicks on the audience group checkbox, only the audience checkboxes under it will be checked also.

currently i have the following, but with a little bug, when i clicked on an audience group checkbox, all the audience checkbox, even those not under is also checked. i want only those audience under that audience group will be checked.

you can see more of my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/CVnTy/

i have this example html:

```
<div class='audience-group'>
    <input type='checkbox' class='audience-group-checkbox' value='9' />
    <div class='audience-group-name'>
        JGG Enterprises
    </div>
    <div class='audience'>
        <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='7' />
        <div class='audience-name'>
            Mucho, George
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='audience'>
        <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='9' />
        <div class='audience-name'>
            Bo, Jen
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='audience'>
        <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='10' />
        <div class='audience-name'>
            Gin, Junto
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='audience'>
        <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='12' />
        <div class='audience-name'>
            Molina, Greg
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='audience'>
        <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='36' />
        <div class='audience-name'>
            Berkely, Dada
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class='audience-group'>
        <input type='checkbox' class='audience-group-checkbox' value='8' />
        <div class='audience-group-name'>
            GBA Inc.
        </div>
        <div class='audience'>
            <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='1' />
            <div class='audience-name'>
                Kapate, Jones
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='audience'>
            <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='2' />
            <div class='audience-name'>
                Bingo, Gringo
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='audience'>
            <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='4' />
            <div class='audience-name'>
                Doe, John
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='audience'>
            <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='8' />
            <div class='audience-name'>
                Merio, Horhe
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='audience'>
            <input type='checkbox' class='audience-checkbox' value='35' />
            <div class='audience-name'>
                Dalisay, JM
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and my jquery code:

```
$('.audience-group-name').click(function() {
    if ($(this).nextUntil('.audience-group').length) {
        $(this).nextUntil('.audience-group').toggle();
    } else {
        alert('No audience under this group.');
    }
});

$('.audience-group-checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $('.audience-checkbox').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

i'm kinda new to jquery, thanks for any help! :)

Comment: No need for the .each() ... the .click() will automatically be attached to each element of the class audience-group-checkbox when using `$('.audience-group-checkbox').click()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `each` loop you're currently using, you can use something like this instead:

```
$('.audience-group-checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".audience-group").find(".audience-checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked); 
});
```

This gets the ancestor `.audience-group` element ([`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) - `parent` would also work here, if your HTML will always be as shown in the question), then gets all descendant elements with class "audience-checkbox" ([`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)). Note that I've also used [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr`, since `checked` is a DOM property. I've also used `this.checked` rather than wrapping `this` in another jQuery object, simply because it's shorter and faster to access the property on the DOM element itself.

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CVnTy/1/).

Note that you don't need the `each`. The majority of jQuery methods apply to all elements in the matched set, and `click` (and all event handler methods for that matter) is no exception.

Comment: this is working too, thanks @James Allardice, i got more understanding! :)

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
$('.audience-group-checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $('.audience-checkbox').attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

`$('.audience-checkbox')` will re-select all elements that have class `audience-checkbox`.

What you probably want to do is only change the attribute for the item that was clicked, correct?

That would be...

```
$('.audience-group-checkbox').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
});
```

By the way, when you do this kind of thing, be aware that some browsers will do this behavior by default, so you'll end up with a situation where some browsers will work like you expect, and others will check the box twice (the first time changing it and the 2nd tome changing it  back).  I've found unless you have a really good reason for doing so, you should just let the browser handle checking and unchecking.

It's possible to prevent the browser default with something like...

`.click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); })`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you already had the code fro expand/collapse. All you need is to extend it a bit [like so](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/CVnTy/5/). I also took the liberty of simplifying your code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.audience-group-checkbox').click(function() {
    $(this).find('.audience-checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//add event handler to all '.audience-group-checkbox' elements
$('.audience-group-checkbox').click(function() {

    //cache this element
    var $this = $(this);

    //select the parent of this object and then find all the '.audience-checkbox' elements under it
    $this.parent().find('.audience-checkbox').prop('checked', $this.is(':checked'));
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k57Tp/

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to use an each for assigning your click event. If you just replace that with:

```
$('.audience-checkbox').click(function(){
   $(this).attr('checked', true);
})
```

Comment: Agree, though you shouldn't be setting `checked` on `this`, and it doesn't really touch the actual question.